# Coordinates for drawing: Use floating point vs. integer?

Tags: java, floating-point, coordinates, graphics2d

Are there any advantages of using floating-point coordinates vs. integer coordinates when drawing on a `Graphics2D` for use on a screen display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of stuff that you want to draw.

If you are drawing "synthetic" things like user interface widgets, for example buttons and such, then it makes sense to stick with integer coordinates.

On the other hand if you are drawing "organic" things like a representation of a triangle, or edges that connect vertices in a graphs then it makes sense to use floating point.

Another way to think of it is to model your scene as close to the real coordinates as you can using floating point values and let the Graphics2D engine figure out where the coordinates go (in pixel coordinates) when drawing on screen.